How many posts did the courtyard of the Holy Tabernacle have?
Exodus 27:9-16 says:


Make a courtyard for the tabernacle. The south side shall be a hundred cubits[c] long and is to have curtains of finely twisted linen,
with twenty posts and twenty bronze bases and with silver hooks and bands on the posts.
The north side shall also be a hundred cubits long and is to have curtains, with twenty posts and twenty bronze bases and with silver hooks and bands on the posts.
The west end of the courtyard shall be fifty cubits[d] wide and have curtains, with ten posts and ten bases.
On the east end, toward the sunrise, the courtyard shall also be fifty cubits wide.
Curtains fifteen cubits[e] long are to be on one side of the entrance, with three posts and three bases,
and curtains fifteen cubits long are to be on the other side, with three posts and three bases.
For the entrance to the courtyard, provide a curtain twenty cubits[f] long, of blue, purple and scarlet yarn and finely twisted linen—the work of an embroiderer—with four posts and four bases


So south and north has 20-20, west has 10 and east has 3+3 with curtains and 4 for the entrance. That adds up to 60. But shouldn't it be 56 because the 4 corners were mentioned twice?
60 makes sense because you can have 10 & 20 evenly spaced 5 cubit segments with the extra 4 posts. Without them, you would have 10 posts creating 9 ~5.55 cubit segments and 20 posts creating 19 ~5.26 cubit segments which aren't equal.
But if there are indeed 60 posts, why does the scripture says 10 or 20 posts on a side, when that side clearly has 11 and 21 posts?

We can only be as specific about this as Exodus, and they didn't include a diagram.
It's usually said 60 not 56, because it's assumed the corners aren't counted twice due to the tendency for inclusive counting. That gives diagrams like this example:-


But there is also a description in Josephus of 48 pillars:-
https://www.sefaria.org/The_Antiquities_of_the_Jews.3.6.3?lang=bi
Which is matched in the Bamidbar Rabbah (c.220AD):-
https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.6.4?ven=The_Sefaria_Midrash_Rabbah,_2022&lang=bi
And might have looked like this-

(both diagrams linked from https://partmcveighinjudicial.z21.web.core.windows.net/diagram-of-the-tabernacle-and-basic-layout.html)
It isn't known why Josephus has a different number, or if the Midrash gets its count of 48 from him.
Whether the assumption about inclusive counting stands is a whole other question about the history of ideas. Some timespans elsewhere in the scripture don't work so well with it - but it looks like how Moses (or the author of Exodus) might be counting. He doesn't say e.g. x cubits by y cubits in total with a post every 5 cubits... or 60 posts less 4 for the corners.
I'm from a deconstructionist linguistic framework so I just see [list of two-digit-numbers conveying specificity and detail] and move on. I respectfully leave it to others to predict when the UFOs will land. If I was wanting to build a reconstruction to fit on the back of a small lorry for a touring evangelical ministry, I'd definitely go with the Jewish version. But there are strong views. Moses doesn't explicitly say how he counts the posts in buildings - and there aren't many other examples to try and deduce it from.
